# Distriqt push notification handle on start app from notification centre

Tags: air, notifications, push-notification

I've just bought Distriqt ANE pack and can't get Push Notification worked for some case.
When application isn't started and I receive PN it shows in notification area, but when I try to open app from notification centre ( clicking by notification )  I can't get access to PN which opened application.

I've read documentation and asked Distriqt support but with no luck.
In docs we have:

> Not running: A notification is displayed in the notification area.
>   When clicked the application is started. When you call register()
>   you'll immediately receive the notification event.

Support team answered:

> You need to make sure you add the listener for notifications before
>   you call register. You should receive the notification immediately
>   when you call register if the application was started from the
>   notification center

My code:

```
PushNotifications.init( PN_DEV_KEY ); //it doesnt init for 2nd time!
if(PushNotifications.isSupported) {
PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.REGISTERING, onPnRegistering );
PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.REGISTER_SUCCESS, pnRegisterResult );
PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.UNREGISTERED, pn_unregisterSuccessHandler );
PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.NOTIFICATION, onPushNotification );
PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION,  onForegroundNotificationReceived );
PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.ERROR, pn_errorHandler );
var registerResult:Boolean = PushNotifications.service.register(GCM_SENDER_ID);
```

But after register call no event has fired. It just do standard register routine and that's it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was only added in one of the more recent releases. Always try to update your extensions before reporting a bug.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to the latest version 2.6.iOS.2.1  from GitHub
and it works just fine.